# What would be the right way to declare an array within a script that will be called by cron?

Tags: arrays, shell, scripting, cron, ksh

I have written a KornShell (ksh) script that sets an array the following way:

```
set -A fruits Apple Orange Banana Strawberry
```

but when I am trying to run it from within cron, it raises the following error:

```
Your "cron" job on myhost
/myScript.sh

produced the following output:

myScript.sh: -A: bad option(s)
```

I have tried many crontab syntax variants, such as:

Attempt 1:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /path/to/script/myScript.sh
```

Attempt 2:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /path/to/script/./myScript.sh
```

Attempt 3:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * cd /path/to/script && ./myScript.sh
```

Any workaround would be sincerely appreciated. Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure it's the best way to do it, I've managed to solve it this way:

Attempt 4:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * cd /path/to/script && ksh ./myScript.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

`*/5 * * * * cd /path/to/script && ksh ./myScript.sh` :- it will run every 5 mins. 
Define Path variables also in the cron itself.

Answer (score 2):

Does `myScript.sh` start with

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

(or whatever the path is for your ksh)?

Comment: If it does start with #!/bin/ksh and still doesn't work as a Kornshell script, could it be that the script itself is not executable and that the cron job is therefore trying to run it as Bourne (on Linux, Bash) shell?