# Set the contents of a file in multiple variables

Tags: unix

I am new to writing Unix scripts. I need to set the contents of file 1 to variables. The variables that were created in file 1 needs to be pasted/copied to file 2 at a specific line number.

File 1 (Input)Contents: Contents I had used grep/awk to extract the required words from another text file.  I need help in converting the contents extracted into separate variables that will be used in the second file at the ${CMD}. if possible

```
userid:Name
pwd:Passwd
study_id:test
isid:testid
.......
.......
```

(Note: Contents in input file are not constant-I could have two to 5 variables at any time. 
File 2 (Output): File 2 is a template that is used to generate a Post installation file to create a Product package.  I need to merge/paste the newly created variable to the ${CMD} line.

```
CMD="$FIX_HOME/shell.ksh"

print "================= Start ${CMD}================"

${CMD} <Variables are set at this line>

Print "Exit form ${CMD} <$?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already creating file 1, you can modify the format in which you create it to make it easier for yourself.  Write the variables you need in the format:

```
userID="Name Surname"
pwd=Passwd
study_id=test
isid=testid
```

You can then read these into your script with the dot command (Bourne Shell, Korn Shell, Bash) or source (C Shell, Bash again).  Note the use of quotes around the value containing spaces.  You might use single quotes, but then handling "Martin O'Rourke" is harder.  If you can't trust the data source, there is a lot of cleaning up to do before this is safe.

You then need to specify how the variables are passed to `${CMD}` on the line.  The other tricky item is knowing which variables were set, because you presumably want to pass only those variables and not all possible variables.  And spaces in arguments definitely complicate things.

If you have Bash 4.x (3.x is not sufficient), you can use an associative array.

```
CMD="$FIX_HOME/shell.ksh"
declare -A array
. file1                            # Set variable values
for name in $(sed 's/=.*//' file1) # Get variable names
do
    x=$(eval echo "\$$name")
    array[$name]="-$name=$x"
done

echo "================= Start ${CMD} ================"

${CMD} "${array[@]}"

echo "================= Exit from ${CMD} <$?> ================="
```

Given the data file:

```
name="Martin O'Rourke"
id=21131
testid=P/23/41
isis=N23-45112
```

and when run with `CMD=al` where `al` is a program that echoes its arguments, one per line, the output from that was as shown - note that the arguments were not in the order in which they were entered:

```
$ bash-4.1 test.script
================= Start al ================
-name=name
-isis=N23-45112
-id=21131
-testid=P/23/41
================= Exit from al <0> =================
$
```

If you have an earlier version of bash, you'll need to use an indexed array, which might have advantages in the the order of the elements on the command line will be determinate.  The downside is that you need to generate the distinct indexes.

However, this could be radically over-complicating things.

```
CMD="$FIX_HOME/shell.ksh"

echo "================= Start ${CMD} ================"

${CMD} $(<file1)

echo "================= Exit from ${CMD} <$?> ================="
```

Or, if you want the dashes in front of the option names:

```
CMD="$FIX_HOME/shell.ksh"

echo "================= Start ${CMD} ================"

${CMD} $(sed 's/^/-/' file1)

echo "================= Exit from ${CMD} <$?> ================="
```

There are other ways you might want to work this, but it depends on what you really wanted to see as the argument list for your `${CMD}`.

Comment: Thanks alot Jonathan - I had aready did what you suggested in step 1.I am using Korn shell not sure if the version I am using will handle associative array or index array. I was thinking on using array, but I lacked the confident. I appreciate the samples you provided.

Comment: I am using ksh shell: I need to generate distinct indexes because the order of the element is important in the CMD line. I created the following

Comment: I am using ksh shell: I need to generate distinct indexes because the order of the element is important in the CMD line. I created the following                                                           $> For wordlist in $(cat  myfile), do
>wordlist[$I]=$word
>I=$((I +1 ))
>Done
Question: Do I have to add the Set -A command for all variables to be place on the same?

Comment: @Ayla: the `declare -A` is a `bash` extension that does associative arrays.  You just need a regular, integer-indexed array, and at most you need to define the array.  I found this [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306531/what-would-be-the-right-way-to-declare-an-array-within-a-script-that-will-be-call) question which indicates that `set -A variable value1 value2 value3` is the right way to do things.  Good luck.